# How to perform conditional delete in multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need your help the problem description is given

The array is as follows

The given array is the sample. The main array contains many entries as follow where username can differ.

Case 1:

```
$my_array = Array
(
0 => Array
    (
        'username' => Pete,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>no
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        'username' => Pete,
        'userid' => 2,
        'option'=>yes
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'username' => John,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>no
    )
3 => Array
    (
        'username' => John,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>yes
    )

) ;
```

Case 2:

```
$my_array = Array
(
0 => Array
    (
        'username' => Pete,
        'userid' => 2,
        'option'=>yes
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        'username' => Pete,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>no
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        'username' => John,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>no
    )
3 => Array
    (
        'username' => John,
        'userid' => 1,
        'option'=>yes
    )

) ;
```

I want to delete the element where 'username'=>Pete and 'Option'=>no

So the output should be looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [username] => Pete
        [userid] => 2
        [option] => yes
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [username] => John
        [userid] => 1
        [option] => yes
    )
)
```

All element of sub array can be same but option field either yes or no.

Please help me

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP, please use appropriate tags. I've removed the CakePHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can achieve that:

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value){
    if($value['username'] == 'Pete' && $value['option'] == 'yes'){
        unset($my_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this solution work with username=pete, If in case many instances with different username come then what I have to do?

Comment: I understood that you only wanted to delete when the user comes with Pete. If you just want to delete when the option is yes no mather what name is inserted you just have to evaluate the condition of the $value['option']

Comment: You said that you " want to delete the element where 'username'=>Pete and 'Option'=>no", but what you really want is to delete all the entries that have 'option' => 'no'?

Comment: I  want to delete the element where 'username'=>Pete or john and 'Option'=>no if some entry is like username =>'bob' and option =>no then entry of bob will not delete

Answer (score 1):

this can be a solution

```
$result = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    if(!($value['username']=="Pete" && $value['options']=="no"))
        array_push($result, $value);
}
```

Comment: What I was trying to say. Good that you created a code example :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop! If the current value for `username = pete` add a variable `user=true`;
Then after that check `if(option == no){ if(user==true){ DELETE ROW } }`

Comment: But this solution work with username=pete, If in case many instances with different username come then what I have to do? for example john entry will be similar to pete then what I have to do?

Comment: Well basically what you would do is `if($val['username'] == "Pete"){ $pete = true; } //Other code here 
if($val['options'] == "No"){ if($pete){ DELETE YOUR VALUES HERE } } ` Essentially what this will do is add a boolean variable to true if the current username == Pete. Then if the boo value is true you can delete whatever from the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
>>> array_filter($my_array, 
        function($obj){
           return $obj["option"] !== "no" || $obj["username"] !== "Pete";
        }
    )
=> [
       1 => [
           "username" => "Pete",
           "userid"   => 2,
           "option"   => "yes"
       ],
       2 => [
           "username" => "John",
           "userid"   => 1,
           "option"   => "no"
       ]
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the function name suggests, you should use `array_filter()`

```
$my_array = array_filter($my_array, function($v){
    return ($v['username'] != 'Pete' && $v['option'] != 'no');
});
```